# Stay on page when clicking annotation in YT player

Tags: youtube-api

I am making an interactive video series in which the viewer can click the annotations to view another video of mine. I have the embedded player on my website, but when I click the annotation linking to another video, it opens a new tab where the video will play on YouTube. How can I make it so that the viewer watches the new video in the same embedded player, without leaving the site?

Comment: I believe they can right-click to open in a new window/tab.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want the videos in the links in the annotations to play in a new window/tab, but in the player on my website.

Answer (score 0):

This is off the top of my head, so not 100% sure, but wourth a try.

First off, you wil need to use the api embedded player. Then you can target it.
You will then need to script the links to target it. Thinking about it, it might not work as the player is "hosted" off your page.

A different way that might be better and should work, is to do a "GET" request on your page and reload your page using the ID to load the required video.

EG.. *http: //www.yoursite.com/player.php?videoID*=***VideoID*** as link.

I use this in my site for some things, but never tried it with annotations, but should work.